# xmlstarlet: query a value if another value is present

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

Here is my [xml file](https://github.com/opendaylight/integration-distribution/blob/master/features/repos/index/pom.xml) where I am trying to query and print the list of all the id's in the file where `avtivebyDefault` is set to `true`.

For this am using `xmlstarlet sel` with the following options:

`$ xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m '/x:project/x:profiles/x:profile/x:activation[x:activeByDefault="true"]' -v /x:project/x:profiles/x:profile/x:id pom.xml | sort -u
aaa
alto
bgpcep
bier
coe
controller
daexim
distribution
dlux
dluxapps
eman
faas
genius
groupbasedpolicy
honeycombvbd
infrautils
jsonrpc
l2switch
lispflowmapping
nemo
netconf
netvirt
neutron
nic
ocpplugin
odlparent
ofconfig
openflowplugin
ovsdb
p4plugin
packetcable
sfc
snmp
snmp4sdn
sxp
tsdr
unimgr
usc
vtn
vtnaaa`

There are two issues here firstly it prints all the id's even if they are set as `false` and second the concats by printing the first and last id together (ex `vtnaaa` from the last line of the output which is incorrect). What am I missing in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this part of the command:

```
-m '/x:project/x:profiles/x:profile/x:activation[x:activeByDefault="true"]' -v /x:project/x:profiles/x:profile/x:id
```

to this:

```
-m '/x:project/x:profiles/x:profile[x:activation/x:activeByDefault="true"]/x:id' -v .
```

To separate the values, try using either `-n` for newlines or change the -v to `-v concat(.,' ')` for a space.

Example...

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -t -m "/x:project/x:profiles/x:profile[x:activation/x:activeByDefault='true']/x:id" -v . -n pom.xml
aaa
alto
bgpcep
bier
coe
controller
daexim
distribution
dlux
dluxapps
genius
groupbasedpolicy
honeycombvbd
infrautils
jsonrpc
l2switch
lispflowmapping
nemo
netconf
netvirt
neutron
odlparent
ofconfig
openflowplugin
ovsdb
p4plugin
packetcable
sfc
snmp
snmp4sdn
sxp
tsdr
usc
vtn
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not work, can you provide a tested answer. Also using `-v .` print all id;s as a single word. which is not correct.

Comment: @askb - Unless I'm missing something, it works for me. See the example in my update. If it's still incorrect, please point out exactly what is incorrect (what values are missing or incorrectly included).

Comment: Does the trick, -n was missing in my cmd, which did not print the newlines initially. Now it works as expected.